# Regex Optional Matches

Tags: php, regex, option-type

I'm trying to match two types of strings using the `preg_match` function in PHP which could be the following.

- '_mything_to_newthing'
- '_onething'
- '_mything_to_newthing_and_some_stuff'

In the third one above, I only want the "mything" and "newthing" so everything that comes after the third part is just some optional text the user could add. Ideally out of the regex would come in the cases of above;

- 'mything', 'newthing'
- 'onething'
- 'mything', 'newthing'

The patterns should match a-zA-Z0-9 if possible :-)

My regex is terrible, so any help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about `_` deliminated text:

```
$regex = '/^_([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(|_to_([a-zA-Z0-9]+).*)$/';

$string = '_mything_to_newthing_and_some_stuff';
preg_match($regex, $string, $match);
$match = array(
    0 => '_mything_to_newthing_and_some_stuff',
    1 => 'mything',
    2 => '_to_newthing_and_some_stuff',
    3 => 'newthing',
);
```

As far as anything farther, please provide more details and better sample text/output

**Edit:** You could always just use `explode`:

```
$parts = explode('_', $string);
$parts = array(
    0 => '',
    1 => 'mything',
    2 => 'to',
    3 => 'newthing',
    4 => 'and',
    5 => 'some',
    6 => 'stuff',
);
```

As long as the format is consistent, it should work well...

Comment: Thanks! You know.. I never thought of it as `_` delimitated text! I might as well just use `explode()` ;)